# declare variable over Sessions

Tags: powershell, variables, scopes

I start a PowerShell script that calls a function with `Invoke-Command` on another computer. I want to declare a variable that is available over all this sessions.

```
$var = "global"

function do-function{
    $var = "function"
    return $var
}

$var
invoke-command -ComputerName NameOfComputer -scriptblock  ${function:do-function}
$var
```

output:

```
global
function
global
```

My target is to get:

```
global
function
function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the return value from the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet to the variable:

```
$var = "global"

function do-function{
    $var = "function"
    return $var
}

$var
$var = invoke-command -ComputerName NameOfComputer -scriptblock  ${function:do-function}
$var
```

Also, a `scriptblock` can be defined as follow:

```
$myScriptBlock = {
    # ....
}

invoke-command -ComputerName NameOfComputer -scriptblock $myScriptBlock
```